# How to use WebSockets from SilverLight

Tags: silverlight, websocket, websocket4net

Can Silverlight use web socket?

I saw samples in Codeplex's SuperWebsocket and Websocket4Net and they are all not working, unfortunately.

How to use it. Any working sample exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its easy. SL can use javascripts.